# How to list all unused elastic IPs and release them using boto3

Tags: python, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, boto, boto3

I am using boto3, I need to list all elastic IPs, find the ones that are not associated with any instance and release them.

What I am doing is:

```
import boto3   
ec2 = boto3.resource('ec2')
```

Then I could list all volumes as this:

```
for volume in ec2.volumes.all():
```

Or all instances like this:

```
for instance in ec2.instances.all():
```

But I don't know how to list all elastic IPs.

The boto3 documentation lists the object ClassicAddress which is what I need to have in order to release the IP.

http://boto3.readthedocs.io/en/latest/reference/services/ec2.html#classicaddress

However, I don't know how to get a collection of all the ClassicAddresses

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I got it working with this code:

```
def elastic_ips_cleanup():
    """ Cleanup elastic IPs that are not being used """
    client = boto3.client('ec2')
    addresses_dict = client.describe_addresses()
    for eip_dict in addresses_dict['Addresses']:
        if "InstanceId" not in eip_dict:
            print (eip_dict['PublicIp'] +
                   " doesn't have any instances associated, releasing")
            client.release_address(AllocationId=eip_dict['AllocationId'])
```

Answer (score 8):

We can just check if the EIP has an eni associated with it. This way it will overcome the issue of whether the EIP is associated with a NAT or a EC2.

Just using mkreder's code and making a small change to check the **NetworkInterfaceId** instead of the **InstanceId**

```
import boto3
client = boto3.client('ec2')
addresses_dict = client.describe_addresses()
for eip_dict in addresses_dict['Addresses']:
    if "NetworkInterfaceId" not in eip_dict:
        print(eip_dict['PublicIp'])
        client.release_address(AllocationId=eip_dict['AllocationId'])
```

No matter if the EIP is associated to a NAT or a EC2, it will have an network interface attached, although when attached to a NAT it does not have a InstanceId.

Answer (score 0):

have used:

```
if "InstanceId" not in eip_dict:
                if "NetworkInterfaceId" not in eip_dict:
```

Answer (score -1):

I would not use mkreder's code, because it can release EIP that are effectively not attached to an instance, but **also** those which are attached to a NAT Gateway in a VPC.
Hopefully I ran this code using

```
DryRun = True
```

Comment: Can you please improve your post and describe what you would instead?

Comment: sorry about that, my scenario doesn't have NAT gateways. It would be nice if you can provide an updated version with this fix so that I can mark your question as correct just in case someone else gets to this page